# Active perl cuts out "^" from @ARGV

Tags: perl, windows-7, argv

The following code works only on mac, but not on windows7.

```
perl -e "print @ARGV" aaa^bbb
```

On Mac (perl 5.10, darwin) it prints out as expected: aaa^bbb

On Windows 7,32bit (ActivePerl 5.12) it prints out: aaabbb

The "^" character is thrown out of @ARGV.
This character is part of a filename that I'm using the script with, so I need to be able to read it from @ARGV.

I tried using "aaa\^bbb" but it just prints out "aaa\bbb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work on [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), either.  However, you can get around this by passing the argument into quotes:

```
perl -e "print @ARGV" "aaa^bbb"
```

Using Strawberry Perl on Windows 7, the output is

```
aaa^bbb
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not ActivePerl that's discarding the `^` character, it's the Windows command prompt:

```
C:\>echo aaa^bbb
aaabbb
```

You need to quote the argument:

```
C:\>perl -e "print @ARGV" "aaa^bbb"
aaa^bbb
```

Or you can escape it with a second caret:

```
C:\>perl -e "print @ARGV" aaa^^bbb
aaa^bbb
```

The caret `^` is an escape character, similar to `\` in Unix shells.